# Coil winding sense in dual voltage power supply

Tags: power-supply, transformer, ripple, winding

[image: dual bridge voltage power supply]
Hello is the sense of the B winding in the transformer (same as A or opposite than A) can have any effect on the powered circuit?

Maybe due to the fact that the AC ripple of the negative rail  is out in phase with the ripple in the positive rail and then worse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the output of the rectifier is full-wave rectified it cannot make any difference which way the transformer coils are wired.

[image]

*Figure 1. Full-wave rectified signal will be the same for either polarity of AC.*

You can save one rectifier by using a "centre-tapped" arrangement.

[image]

*Figure 2. The centre-tapped arrangement uses one bridge rectifier.*

This arrangement is also a little more efficient as the current flows through only one diode on its way from the transformer outer taps back to the centre-tap resulting in a voltage loss of only 0.7 V compared with 1.4 V for the arrangement shown in the question.